# Android - Unity3D: setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) crashes

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a unity project and I use a Android (java) plugin to get camera data. I draw this on a TextureView.
I want to hide/show this view when I press a button in unity.
But my app crashes when I setVisibility

onCreate

```
UnityPlayer.currentActivity.addContentView(texView, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(400, 400));
```

java:

```
public void HideVideo()
{
    //Hide view
    _TextureView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Is there an extra function I need to call, or may I only call it on certain times?

None of these thins work, they all make my app crash.

```
    _TextureView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    _TextureView.setActivated(false);
    _TextureView.setAlpha(0);
    _TextureView.setTranslationY(-1000);
```

Comment: I'm not sure but you can still try http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ if you can't find a solution here.

Comment: I have and added some extra info here.

Answer (score 0):

I have made a work around, now I set a boolean and in the onSurfaceTextureUpdated callback I set the alpha.

```
public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surface)
{
    //Visibility changed
    if(_isVisibleChanged == true)
    {
        //Show video
        if(_isVisible)
            _TextureView.setAlpha(1);

        //Hide video
        else
            _TextureView.setAlpha(0);

        //Visibility updated
        _isVisibleChanged = false;
    }
}
```

But still don't understand why it crashes when not inside this function. Does anybody have an answer to that?